# The mapping of the JSON type in "gorm gen database to struct" can cause errors during creation if the value is not passed

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

table：

```
type SQL
CREATE TABLE `user_profile` (
  `uuid` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE COMMENT 'uuid',
  `user_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'user id',
  `nickname` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'nickname',
  `age` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'age',
  `active` bool NOT NULL DEFAULT true COMMENT 'whether the user is active',
  `rank` float NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'user rank',
  `other` json COMMENT 'other personal information',
  `card` json COMMENT 'introduction card',
  `state` enum('on', 'off') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on' COMMENT 'blacklist: off - on',
  `is_del` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'whether the record is deleted',
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'the time when the record is created',
  `update_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'the time when the record is updated',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_uuid` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='user profile table';
```

Error：

> Error 3140 (22032): Invalid JSON text: "The document is empty." at
> position 0 in value for column 'user_profile.other'.

"I used the gorm gen database to struct command to map the database to Golang structs, but the official documentation does not provide a good solution to the problem. Therefore, I hope someone can provide a solution."

Comment: Hey, what do you mean with "value not passed"? Is the table empty?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a default value for your JSON fields. it should be `'[]'`.